# Instagram application is in pending review status

Tags: instagram-api

I have created an application on Instagram and submitted for review 2 days ago but it is still in pending status. Would someone help me, please?

Thank you

Comment: As I heard instagram does not approve new apps anymore. You need to submit your app through Facebook only

Comment: @Mohamm6d so we can submit an app to use Instagram social login, through Facebook? how?

Comment: @Mohamm6d, I am waiting for one month but still, my application is in the `Pending Review` in the `Instagram developer`.

Answer (score 1):

the instagram review process can take up to a month regarding other users and my experience.

Just wait and keep patience.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted my instagram app for review in month of July 2018 (3 months ago) and still it is pending review. I think they have stopped accepting new apps for instagram legacy platform. They have created Instagram Graph API but as of now, it can only be used for Instagram Business Account users. They might implement these new API for normal instagram users as well in future.